# HTML Canvas "source-atop" to draw only the previously drawn shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I can't figure out how to get the canvas "source-atop" to draw subsequent drawings inside ONLY the previously drawn shape, instead of "all" previously shapes. Like this code. It draws a "shadow" rectangle, then draws a rectangle to act as the "object", then source-atop, then I want the next drawn rectangle to be clipped inside the previously drawn one (the "object"), but instead it clips inside the "shadow". Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="theCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="externalJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded () {
    canvasApp();
}
function canvasApp() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = '#999999';// this rectangle is supposed to be the "shadow"
    context.fillRect(42, 42, 350, 150);
    context.fillStyle = '#dddddd';// this rectangle is supposed to be on top..."
    context.fillRect(35, 35, 350, 150);

    context.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";

    context.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
    context.fillRect(100, 100, 350, 150);//... and then this rectangle is supposed to be clipped inside the previously 

drawn one... not the shadow one
}
```

Comment: Compositing affects all existing pixels vs all new pixels, so you can't "layer" to affect (or not affect) just the most recently existing pixels. If you want to layer your compositing you will need to do that on a second canvas(probably in-memory) and then `drawImage` the in-memory canvas to the main canvas.

Answer (score 1):

`source over` is the default comp operation and always draws pixels over those that exist. You need to use `source-atop` and `destination-over`.

Also when using comp operations the order of rendering is no longer back to front. In this case the shadow is drawn last. If it were to be draw first it would interfere with the `source-atop` operation.

Below is one way of doing it. But I would suggest that you use `ctx.clip()` as this example is better suited to `ctx.clip()` because of the simplicity of the shapes. Use the comps only for situations where you have very complex images and need per pixel control of clipping.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// draw a circle
function drawCircle(x,y){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,150,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
}

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // ensure a clear canvas
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";  // draw the cyan circle normaly
ctx.fillStyle = "#3AE";
drawCircle(200,200);   // draw the main circle


ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";  // draw the new pixels from source 
                                               // ontop of any existing pixels 
                                               // and not where the are no pixels
ctx.fillStyle = "#F70";
drawCircle(300,300);  // draw the clipped circle;

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";  // draw the shadow. 
                                                    // Where pixels in destination
                                                    // stay ontop.
ctx.fillStyle = "#888";
drawCircle(210,210);  // draw the shadow;
```

```css
#canV {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "canV" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```